# get the attachement files from REST API

Tags: javascript, rest, attachments, file

I use REST API SharePoint 2013 to get the items from list: And and I want to get the Attachments Files, How can i do that?

This the code :

```
function getListItems(url, listname, query, complete, failure) {

    // Executing our items via an ajax request
    $.ajax({
        url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items" + query,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            complete(data); // Returns JSON collection of the results

        },
        error: function (data) {
            //failure(data);
            alert("failure");
        }
    });

}
```

I use the console of my navigator : `data.d.results[5].Attachments=true`

```
data.d.results[0].AttachmentFiles.__deferred.uri= http://wbcjdyzd/_api/Web/Lists(guid'ba46572a-3bac-4813-8692-d890fbb88b29')/Items(14)/AttachmentFiles
```

But I don't get the URL of the file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to `$select` and `$expand` the `AttachmentFiles` property for your list items if you want to select many items from the list.

```
_api/lists/getByTitle('MyList')/items?$select=AttachmentFiles,Title&$expand=AttachmentFiles
```

Then you can get attachment info (if it exists) in the `AttachmentFiles` property of your list item which will be an array of AttachmentFile objects.

I suggest you just check out the return values in your dev tools to inspect the structure with something like:

```
$.getJSON("/_api/lists/getByTitle('MyList')/items?$select=AttachmentFiles,Title&$expand=AttachmentFiles", 
    function(data) { console.log(data) })
```

But you can do something like retrieve the file's URL with:

```
data.value[0].AttachmentFiles[0].ServerRelativeUrl
```

If your list item doesn't have any attachments, the `AttachmentFiles` will be an empty array.

I can't seem to get the `$filter` operator to work with the `Attachments` property to filter the results for only those items with attachments -- maybe someone else out there has some experience getting that up and running and would like to add it here =)

Comment: @Jens made a comment that using `$select` and `$expand` doesn't seem to work in a 2013 On-premises environment: I'm beginning to think that the REST API has been patched up by some of the updates Microsoft has been rolling out. This works as advertised for me using SharePoint online as of the time of my answer. Is your on-prem environment up to date with all the CUs?

Comment: What about adding an ID for a specific list item and include the attachment?

Comment: You need to add Attachment in $select, without this it returns error

Comment: Filtering for items with attachments is accomplished via `$filter=Attachments eq 1`.

Comment: @John-M Getting "Column 'Attachments' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user." Using [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest#working-with-files-attached-to-list-items-by-using-rest)

Comment: @AnkitkumarMalde "Attachments", not "Attachment". Careful. It does not recognize the singular form of the word.

Comment: @MayureshSrivastava I know I'm late to the party, but the only way you get an error like that is if the list is corrupt, really missing that column, or you're using the URL against a document library. When you get things like that, try creating a brand new list and use it against a test item you create there by pasting in the URL in a browser, with everything filled in as you think it should be.

Comment: This answer is not fully correct. To get the link you should first test `Attachments` to see if it is `true`, so you need that in the `$select` group. Then yes, you need `AttachmentFiles` in both the `$select` and the `$expand`. Then, the `data.value[0].AttachmentFiles[0].ServerRelativeUrl` you have is wrong. It's where you should assign `var items = data.d.results;` and then `if (items[0].Attachments) { var picLink = items[i].AttachmentFiles.results[0].ServerRelativeUrl; }` -- you left out the `.results`.

Answer (score 11):

Not enough Reputation to add a comment, but DacrioS has cracked it.  I have an on-premises install of Sharepoint 2013 and could not get attachments to show up when using _api/web REST interface.  Until I read this comment: "Try adding Attachments to the select."

Let me be clear:

**This Does Not Work** 
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MYLIST')/items?$filter=Id%20eq%202451&$select=AttachmentFiles&$expand=AttachmentFiles

**This DOES WORK**
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MYLIST')/items?$filter=Id%20eq%202451&$select=Attachments,AttachmentFiles&$expand=AttachmentFiles

Notice the ONLY difference between the two queries is the inclusion of Attachments in the $select statement.  Add that and booya - I get Attachment files.

Comment: getting "The field or property 'Attachments' does not exist."

Comment: @MayureshSrivastava The only way you get an error like that is if the list is corrupt, really missing the column, or you're using a document library. When you get things like that, try creating a brand new list & use it against a test item you create there by pasting the URL into a browser, with everything filled in as you think it should be. Also, you can't use the URL he did because he added a filter for an ID that probably doesn't exist on your list. Take it off: `https://yoursite/sites/SC/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MYLIST')/items?$select=Attachments,AttachmentFiles&$expand=AttachmentFiles`

Answer (score 4):

You can get attachments using

```
var url = url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListTitle')/items(1)/AttachmentFiles";

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    accepts: {
        json: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    method: "GET",
    success: onQuerySuccess,
    error: onQueryError
});

function onQuerySuccess(data) {
    if (data) {
        $.each(data.d.results, function () {
            // do something
            this.ServerRelativeUrl;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting "Column 'Attachments' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user." Using [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest#working-with-files-attached-to-list-items-by-using-rest)

Answer (score 4):

If you get a message like:
`The 'Attachments' column doesn't exists.`

Try adding 'Attachments' to the select, like:
`_api/lists/getByTitle('MyList')/items?$select=Attachment,AttachmentFiles,Title&$expand=AttachmentFiles`

Comment: This does not seem to be an answer to posted question but one of the answers. If you want to comment to author of a question/answer then first attain 50 reputations and get eligible for commenting everywhere.

Comment: @Severino, getting "The field or property 'Attachments' does not exist."

Comment: The select statement has "Attachment", not "Attachments". It should be "Attachments".

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough reputation to comment so I can only "answer" :-( The answer from john-m sounds great but it does not seem to work?

`$select=AttachmentFiles,Title` does return the expected result, AttachmentFiles as deferred url

just `$expand=AttachmentFiles` without any `$select=` does work, gets all fields and an array of attachments

But `$select=AttachmentFiles,Title&$expand=AttachmentFiles` returns an error that

`"value": "Value does not fall within the expected range."`

Looks like here, SP2013 on premise, only select OR expand but not combined :-(

john-m please, does select + expand this actually work for you?

Comment: I added a comment to my own answer in case this gets removed -- is your on-prem environment updated with the CUs by any chance? My answer works as advertised using SP Online

Comment: Working on a new, similar project I learned that using the older/other REST endpoint "_vti_bin/listdata.svc" actually does allow to select, expand, filter better than the new "_api/web/" stuff

Comment: I voted this up because I thought you might've been on to something, but when I tried it, myself, I have no issues with a select on both Attachments and Attachment Files, with an expand on AttachmentFiles.

Answer (score 0):

> //you can re-iterate inside the success to call the Attachments api
>   //for every item inside the data result of the first out ajax call

```
 $.ajax({
        url: Siteurl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items" + query,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            complete(data); // Returns JSON collection of the results
            [].forEach.call(data.d.results,function(value,index){
                 var attachmentsUrl = Siteurl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('"+listname+"')/items("+value.ID+")/AttachmentFiles";
                 $.ajax({
                     url:attachmentsUrl,
                     method:"GET",
                     headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
                     success:function(dataInner){
                        value.Attachments = dataInner.d.results;
                     }
                 });
            });
        },
        error: function (data) {
            //failure(data);
            alert("failure");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `Attachments` so you can test if you have one, and then get and expand `AttachmentFiles`:

```
 var query = "$select=Title,Attachments,AttachmentFiles&$expand=AttachmentFiles";
```

Once you have that in your query string, you combine that with your site's URL where the list is (chop off "/Lists/MyList" and everything after it), with `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle("YourListNameHere")/items`. Your items are in the form of `data.d.results`, so you can loop through them. I assign that to a variable called `items`, and so I get `items[0], items[1], items[2]... items[n]`.

Off of each `items[i]` you can check `items[i].Attachments` if it is `true`. If it is, you can get the link from `items[i].AttachmentFiles.results[0].ServerRelativeUrl`:

```
 var siteUrl = "https://mysite/sites/mysitecollection";
 var query = "$select=Title,Attachments,AttachmentFiles&$expand=AttachmentFiles";
 var picLink = "";

 $.ajax({
    url: siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items" + query,
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success: function (data) {
        var items = data.d.results;
        if (items.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                if (items[i].Title != undefined) {
                    if (items[i].Attachments) {
                        picLink = items[i].AttachmentFiles.results[0].ServerRelativeUrl;
                    }
                }
            } // end loop
        } // end if
    },
    error: function (data) {
        //failure(data);
        alert("failure");
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get the attachments for a specific item from the custom list, you need to have the internal ID of the record item.

Once you have your ID, you can do a rest call, here the rest URL:

```
/_api/lists/getByTitle('{{ListName}}')/items({{ID}})/AttachmentFiles
```

You just need to pass the List name and the item ID.

BR,
jasminb

Comment: Getting "Column 'Attachments' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user." Using [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest#working-with-files-attached-to-list-items-by-using-rest)

Comment: You have to expand `AttachmentFiles`, and this doesn't say how you get the resulting URL of the attachment. You also don't need a specific ID, you can loop through your list items, anyway.