# How to use expand in rest api to get child list records

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, sharepoint-rest-api, lookup-column, modern-experience

We have 2 lists. List A is the parent and List B is the child.

I want child record details when I am querying to the parent list.

Current API:

```
https://url/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ListA')/items?$filter=id eq 'a6bc34' &$orderby= modifiedon desc&$expand=AttachmentFiles&$top=5
```

How can I use the same API to get the related child record details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have added a lookup column to List B which references the list items from List A >> You **cannot** fetch list items from List B when querying the List A using SharePoint REST API.

If you have added a lookup column to List A which references the list items from List B >> You can fetch item details from List B when querying the List A by using `$expand` to expand the lookup column & `$select` to select the individual properties from lookup column like:

```
https://url/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ListA')/items?$select=Id,Title,LookupFromListB/Title&$expand=LookupFromListB
```

Where `LookupFromListB` is the internal name of lookup column in List A and above query fetches `Title` property of lookup item from List B.

You can get the exact internal name of your SharePoint columns by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Comment: if we enable attachments for List does that creates a parent-child relationship between list and attachment table. we can expand attachments from list A.

Comment: Attachments are part of the same list & it does not create a separate list for attachments. You can get the file properties from `AttachmentFiles` property in success function of API call. Check [this thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/126561/get-the-attachement-files-from-rest-api) for more information related to this.

Comment: okay. I got it in SharePoint we cannot expand the child list from the Parent list. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly select the fields you want from AttachmentFiles using the format `AttachmentFiles/<field name>`. For example,

```
https://url/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ListA')/items?$select=Id,Title,AttachmentFiles/Id,AttachmentFiles/Title$filter=id eq 'a6bc34' &$orderby= modifiedon desc&$expand=AttachmentFiles&$top=5
```

This would return the values of the Id and Title field from ListA and the values of the Id and Title field for AttachmentFiles.