# SharePoint 2019 list datatable from lookup column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, list, sharepoint-rest-api, 2019

How do I return a datatable in SharePoint 2019 from list with a lookup column from another list?

[image]

Script used:

```
<table id="Employee" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Title</th>
<th>ID_Number</th>
<th>ID_Number:First_Names</th>
<th>ID_Number:Last_Name</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
</div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
GetItems();
});

function GetItems() {
var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
var oDataUrl = siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('VettingList')/items?$select=Title,ID_Number,ID_Number:First_Names,ID_Number:Last_Name";
$.ajax({
url: oDataUrl,
type: "GET",
dataType: "json",
headers: {
"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
},
success: OnSuccess,
error: OnFailure
});
}

function OnSuccess(data) {
try {
$('#Employee').DataTable({
"aaData": data.d.results,
"aoColumns": [
{
"mData": "Title"
},
{
"mData": "ID_Number"
},
{
"mData": "ID_Number:First_Names"
},
{
"mData": "ID_Number:Last_Name"
}
]
});
} catch (e) {
alert(e.message);
}
}

function OnFailure(data, errMessage) {
alert("Error: " + errMessage);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch item details from Parent list selected in lookup column settings by using `$expand` to expand the lookup column & `$select` to select the individual properties from lookup column like:

```
var oDataUrl = siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('VettingList')/items?$select=Title,ID_Number/ID,ID_Number/First_Names,ID_Number/Last_Name&$expand=ID_Number";
```

Make sure you are using correct **internal names** of your `ID_Number`, `ID_Number:First_Names` and `ID_Number:Last_Name` column in above REST API call.

You can get the internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

For more information, check:

1. [How to use expand in rest api to get child list records](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/300374/how-to-use-expand-in-rest-api-to-get-child-list-records/300386#300386)
2. [REST API $expand issues](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/273030/rest-api-expand-issues/273114#273114)

Comment: The datatable is generated but returns the error: [object Object] for ID_Number

Comment: What is the error message? Are you using the correct names of the columns?

Comment: It doesn't pull any data. I used the following column names: "mData": "Title"
"mData": "ID_Number"
"mData": "ID_Number/First_Names"
"mData": "ID_Number/Last_Name"

Comment: You have to use the internal names of column everywhere. Try adding `console.log(data.d.results)` inside the success function (`function OnSuccess(data) {}`) and see if it returns the array result in browser console.

Comment: I got it. Column name should be: "mData": "Title"
},
{
"mData": "ID_Number.ID_Number"
},
{
"mData": "ID_Number.First_Names"
},
{
"mData": "ID_Number.Last_Name"
}

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you!